# Remove postgres user account on windows 7

Tags: postgresql, windows-7, postgresql-9.2

I want install postgresql (9.2 version) on my local computer (OS: windows 7)

So, in first time at install, I had some error and now, I need just uninstall old postgres, but when I am trying uninstall, I got warning message: `The data directory (bla bla....) and service user account (NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService) have not been removed`

Question: how to remove this old `user account` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to remove the service account if you're going to reinstall. The new install will use the existing user account. That, and the fact that multiple versions might be using it, are why any user account the installer creates isn't removed.

In any case, 9.2 doesn't use the `postgres` user account anymore. By default it installs as `NETWORKSERVICE`.  This is a *windows system account*. You can't remove it even if you want to, and if you did it'd render your system completely nonfunctional. That uninstall message is just a leftover from when the installer used to use the `postgres` account, though it's still useful if you install with a non-default user account. I've reported it to EnterpriseDB as a bug.

Now, if you have an existing data directory you want to get rid of and you know it has no information of any value you should remove it or rename it so the new install doesn't try to just use the existing data directory. The data directory location is shown in the message emitted by the uninstaller.

Comment: EDB have acknowledged the issue; The next patch release of the 9.2 installer and the first release of the final 9.3 installer will omit the message if the `NetworkService` account is used. See this mailing list post: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+OCxoz2Obx2kgzsFJ5JPcvzw8QLvBDtWOaPswN6Z7gvZua+4g@mail.gmail.com

Comment: Thanks very much Mr. Craig Ringer

Comment: Sandeep Thakkar at EnterpriseDB has fixed this installer bug; it'll be gone in releases of the installer made after 2013-07-22.